# Minikube Ingress Controller has no address

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, nginx-ingress

Specs:

- OS: MacOs Big Sur (ARM)
- Docker: 4.0.1
- Minikube version: v1.23.0

## controller-hpa.yaml

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-autoscaling
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v2beta1v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: {{ .Release.Name }}-deployment
  minReplicas: {{ .Values.replicaCountMin }}
  maxReplicas: {{ .Values.replicaCountMax }}
  metrics:
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: cpu
        target:
          type: Utilization
          averageUtilization: 70
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: memory
        target:
          type: Utilization
          averageUtilization: 80
```

## deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-autoscaling
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v2beta1v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: {{ .Release.Name }}-deployment
  minReplicas: {{ .Values.replicaCountMin }}
  maxReplicas: {{ .Values.replicaCountMax }}
  metrics:
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: cpu
        target:
          type: Utilization
          averageUtilization: 70
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: memory
        target:
          type: Utilization
          averageUtilization: 80
```

## ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-hosts
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1

spec:
  defaultBackend: # сервис на который будет уходить трафик по умолчания
    service:
      name: {{ .Release.Name }}-service
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
    - host: fake.myaddress.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: {{ .Release.Name }}-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

## service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-service
  labels:
    env  : prod
    owner: NikitaPavlov
spec:
  selector:
    project: {{ .Release.Name }}    # Selecting PODS with those Labels
  ports:
    - name      : app-listener
      protocol  : TCP
      port      : 80  # Port on Service
      targetPort: 80  # Port on POD
  type: ClusterIP

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-service-tomcat
  labels:
    env  : prod
    owner: NikitaPavlov
spec:
  selector:
    project: {{ .Release.Name }}    # Selecting PODS with those Labels
  ports:
    - name      : app-listener-for-tomcat
      protocol  : TCP
      port      : 8080  # Port on Service
      targetPort: 8080  # Port on POD
  type: ClusterIP
```

Original files here - https://github.com/npavlov/k8s-lesson/tree/main/helm-chart

Steps to reproduce:

- `minikube start --nodes 2`
- `minikube addons enable ingress`
- `minikube addons enable ingress-dns`
- `helm install app helm-chart`

So the issue is: my ingress controller has empty address

[Empty address in the Ingress Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vu7OK.png)

```
➜ kubectl describe ingress  ingress-hosts
Name:             ingress-hosts
Namespace:        default
Address:
Default backend:  app-service:80 (10.244.1.2:80,10.244.1.3:80)
Rules:
  Host                Path  Backends
  ----                ----  --------
  fake.myaddress.com
                      /   app-service:80 (10.244.1.2:80,10.244.1.3:80)
Annotations:          meta.helm.sh/release-name: app
                      meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
                      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
Events:               <none>
```

How to fix that?

Comment: Try removing the defaultBackend part from the ingress definition.  And make sure to add nginx annotations for the ingress

Comment: kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx

Comment: if I will remove defaultBackend, I will receive error 

default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)

Answer (score 0):

Use minikube's tunneling feature.

```bash
minikube tunnel
# enter password if asked.
```

This will bind the IPs to the ingress resource.